# How to make the vertical scrollviewer auto display in groupbox

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, groupbox

below is my xaml structure:

```
 <Grid>        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />         
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Test}" />
        <GroupBox Header = "Test" Grid.Row="1">
             <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Description}" />
        </GroupBox>
 </Grid>
```

My Description is very long, but there's no vertical scrollviewer display in my groupbox. I don't want to set a specific height to the groupbox. Anyone can help?

Comment: Which part should be scrollable? `TextBlock` only or whole `Grid`? Your XAML shows that both `TextBlock` and `GroupBox` are in `Auto` row. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you mean you want the `Grid` to scroll when it has more content than fits in the window, you need to wrap it in the `ScrollViewer`. Nothing else in WPF scrolls by itself.

Comment: @dkozl ,john C, thanks for your reply. I want to the GroupBox is scrollable.

Comment: Just to confirm. Is `GroupBox` really in `Auto` row with _Test_ `TextBlock` or you forgot to put `Grid.Row="1"`?

Comment: @dkozl, sorry, I forgot to put Grid.Row="1" in the question, in my app, I setted it. I have edited the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and wrap it in `ScrollViewer` with `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" />
   <GroupBox Header="Test" Grid.Row="1">
      <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
         <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" />
      </ScrollViewer>
   </GroupBox>       
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but, is there a way to place the scrollviewer in the groupbox? Not outside of it. Thanks!

Comment: Should be the same just change order of tags and wrap `TextBlock` instead of whole `GroupBox`. Check my updated answer